# NullPointerException on expired session

Tags: java, spring, security, session, model-view-controller

I'm using Spring, and I need to expire the session of a user when I update said user. I'm using the following configuration:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean () throws Exception {

    return super.authenticationManagerBean();

}

@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry () {

    return new SessionRegistryImpl();

}
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {    //(5)
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {

    authenticationMgr.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());

}

@Override
protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("*.jsp").authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?failed=1")
            .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")               
        .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout.html")
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(100)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .expiredUrl("/ejercicios-programacion/")
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

}
```

And this is how I expire sessions:

```
public void expireUserSessions(String username) {
    for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
        if (principal instanceof User) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
            if (userDetails.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                for (SessionInformation information : sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(userDetails, false)) {
                    information.expireNow();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When this is done, and I reload the page on the browser where I had my updated user, it will show the Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter$1.onExpiredSessionDetected(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:107)
```

Which redirects to:

```
@Override
public void onExpiredSessionDetected(SessionInformationExpiredEvent event) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = event.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = event.getResponse();
    SessionInformation info = event.getSessionInformation();

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, determineExpiredUrl(request, info));
}
```

In particular, it's the last line of code the one throwing the exception. If I reload the page again, after getting the exception, then everything is fine; I get no exception and I'm logged out. I have no idea why this is happening. Does anybody know?

Comment: Did you try to debug and check if `redirectStrategy` is null on the first method call?

Comment: Thank you. Just checked it, redirectStrategy is null, how do I fix that?

Comment: Update: added @Bean RedirectStrategy with new RedirectStrategyDefault () and I keep getting the same exception

Comment: I am not sure. Sounds like it isn't in the spring context when you first start it. Can you put a breakpoint at your `new RedirectStrategyDefault ()` line and see if it is reached?

Comment: I have just checked, it is indeed reached. Eclipse gives me an error "missing line numbers" but when I take out that particular breakpoint it works so I'm guessing that part of the code is being reached. By the way, I just took a look at the class ConcurrentSessionFilter, to which I'm trying to inject the bean, and redirectStrategy is not an autowired field, I honestly don't know what's going on with this

Comment: That's weird, I'm not sure what is going on. Unfortunately I have to leave for today, I hope someone else can help!

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve this problem. The answer is to use your own ConcurrentSessionFilter, since many of the methods used by the default one are deprecated. Add this bean:

```
 @Bean public ConcurrentSessionFilter concurrentSessionFilter() {

    ConcurrentSessionFilter c = new ConcurrentSessionFilter(sessionRegistry(), new SessionInformationExpiredStrategy() {

        @Override
        public void onExpiredSessionDetected(SessionInformationExpiredEvent event) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest request = event.getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = event.getResponse();
            SessionInformation info = event.getSessionInformation();

            redirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/ejercicios-programacion/");

        }
    });

    return c;

}
```

And do whatever you want in the overwritten method, in my case I used my new RedirectStrategy to move users to the index page.

And then add this to your config method:

```
protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    ...
    // Whatever you want to configure

    http.addFilterBefore(concurrentSessionFilter(), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class);

}
```

I can't believe how unintuitive this was, I don't know how such a simple thing as expiring sessions can be so hard and obtuse in Spring